# How can i change text rotation in Luck Wheel (Android)

Tags: android, github, orientation, android-canvas, android-custom-view

Here the link of GitHub Code https://github.com/thanhniencung/LuckyWheel
I try to change the rotation of canvas using this piece of code

```
 private void drawText(Canvas canvas, float tmpAngle, float sweepAngle, String mStr) {
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addArc(mRange,tmpAngle,sweepAngle);

    float textWidth = mTextPaint.measureText(mStr);
    int hOffset = (int) (mRadius * Math.PI / mLuckyItemList.size()/2-textWidth/2);

    int vOffset = mRadius/2/4;

    canvas.drawTextOnPath(mStr, path, hOffset, vOffset, mTextPaint);
}
```

I want to change orientation of text like picture shown below
[image]

Comment: And you are stuck at....?

Comment: the orientation is fixed and I need to change the orientation, you can check drawText method where it write some string

Comment: @ArslanDurrani I am also using this library. Is there any possibility to get click of slices?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of the [LuckyWheel](https://github.com/thanhniencung/LuckyWheel), when initialising `LuckyItem`s data, you can set the values for `luckyItem.secondaryText` instead of `luckyItem.topText`, and you will have the wanted text orientation.

Like this:

```
        List<LuckyItem> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sectorsTitles.length; i++) {
            LuckyItem luckyItem = new LuckyItem();
            // luckyItem.topText = sectorsTitles[i]; // Don't use this
            luckyItem.secondaryText = sectorsTitles[i]; // Use this instead
            luckyItem.color = Color.parseColor(ROULETTE_COLORS[i]);
            data.add(luckyItem);
        }
        luckyWheelView.setData(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

In XML code you can change the rotation by using

```
android:rotation="120"  (Then any angle you want positive or negative)
```

But, you may need to rotate this image when it is in the bottom and then rotate it again when it is in the top. So you can rotate it programatically whenever you want.

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

textView.setRotation(120);
imageView.setRotation(120);
```

And then if you want to comeback it latter to the position it was in the beginning. You just add the negative sign.

```
textView.setRotation(-120);
imageView.setRotation(-120);
```

Of course, the angle is up to you.

Comment: this is a custom view, not that simple